# Inject function into first blank cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel file like this:

```
+--------------------------+
| Product | Amount | price |
+=========+========+=======+
| Test    | 1      | 20.00 |
+---------+--------+-------+
| Test2   | 2      | 50.00 |
+---------+--------+-------+
| Total   | 3      | 70.00 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

I wan to be able to add as many products as I want, without touching the `total row`.

So, is it possible to automatically find the first empty cell in a column, and insert the `total row` into that row?

Comment: Yes it is possible. `1` Find the last row which has data `2` Insert one row before that. I would recommend recording a macro to see how the code churns out and then simply amend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fill the column B1 with a value 1.
2. To get the row number of the first blank cell, you can use below formula. Set this formula on the cell B2

   ```
   =MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(A:A),0,0),0)
   ```
3. In the cell B3, you can use below formula: This would give you the sum of all the non blank columns

   ```
   =SUM(INDIRECT("A" &B1& ":A" &B2))
   ```

Also refer [here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelslookupfunctions/ss/2013-04-20-excel-sum-offset-formula-tutorial.htm) for further idea of SUM OFFSET function if it would be useful for you.